# Maximal and Minimal Solutions to IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $y^{*}(x)= \frac{x^{2}}{4}$ is the maximal solution and $y_{*}(x) = 0$ is the minimal solution when $x \geq 0$ for the IVP:

$ y^{'} = \sqrt{|y|}$ , $y(0)=0$

I know the solution is of the form $ y(x) = \frac{(x+C)^{2}}{4}$ but I am not sure how to conclude the maximal and minimal solutions.

Comment: Have you seen the definition of maximal and minimal solutions?

Comment: The only definition I have seen is $y_{*}(x) < y(x) < y^{*}(x)$ where $y(x)$ is any solution of the IVP.

Comment: Ok, then I think you just solved your own problem. Note that $C=0$ since $y(0)=0$. It should be clear that $y_*(x)=0<y^*(x)=x^2/4$ for any $x>0$.

Comment: Ok, I see thanks for the comments.